# react-native code to send image to S3 bucket has stopped sending the network request

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-s3, react-native-ios, redux-observable

I have this `redux-observable` epic which sends an image to my AWS S3 bucket using `react-native-aws3`. It has been working for years. But now it has stopped going inside the `.map` and `.catch` code block. I don't even think it is sending a network request anymore. What could be causing this?

code:

```
//@flow

import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3'
import 'redux-observable'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
// $FlowFixMe
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
// $FlowFixMe
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax'
import type { VepoState } from 'src/components/model'
import type { RecordOf } from 'immutable'

import {
  updateAlertModalIsOpen,
  updateAlertModalMessage,
  updateAlertModalTitle
} from 'src/components/formControls/alertModal/action'
import Toast from 'react-native-root-toast'

import 'redux-observable'
import { s3options } from 'src/components/model'
import type { Epic, ActionsObservable } from 'redux-observable'
import type { RequestFulfilledDto, RequestRejectedDto } from 'src/model/ajax'
import {
  uploadAddProductImageFulfilled,
  uploadAddProductImageRejected,
  updateAddProductImageInDb,
  updateAddProductImageInDbFulfilled,
  updateAddProductImageInDbRejected,
  UPLOAD_ADD_PRODUCT_IMAGE,
  UPLOAD_ADD_PRODUCT_IMAGE_FULFILLED,
  UPLOAD_ADD_PRODUCT_IMAGE_REJECTED,
  UPDATE_ADD_PRODUCT_IMAGE_IN_DB,
  UPDATE_ADD_PRODUCT_IMAGE_IN_DB_FULFILLED,
  UPDATE_ADD_PRODUCT_IMAGE_IN_DB_REJECTED,
  UPLOAD_ADD_PRODUCT,
  UPLOAD_ADD_PRODUCT_FULFILLED,
  UPLOAD_ADD_PRODUCT_REJECTED,
  uploadAddProductFulfilled,
  uploadAddProductRejected,
  updateAddProductId
} from './action'
import { deselectAllCategories } from 'src/components/formControls/categoriesMultiselect/action'
import {
  updateLocationAutocompleteSearchText,
  updateShouldHideLocationResults,
  updateLocationAutocompletePlace,
  updateLocationListDisplayed
} from 'src/components/formControls/locationAutocomplete/redux'
import { updateProductImageLink } from 'src/components/formControls/imagePicker/redux'

import { uploadAddProductImage } from 'src/components/product/add/groceryItem/action'


export const uploadAddProductImageEpic = (action$: ActionsObservable<string>) =>
      action$.ofType(UPLOAD_ADD_PRODUCT_IMAGE).mergeMap((action) => {
        return Observable.fromPromise(RNS3.put(action.payload, action.config))
          .map((response) => {
            return uploadAddProductImageFulfilled(response)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            return Observable.of(uploadAddProductImageRejected(error))
          })
      })
```

Comment: I can't load my AWS management console. I think AWS may be down. Can anyone confirm? I would have thought I'd still be seeing a network request made if it was down.

Answer (score 0):

It was AWS management console being down. It just works today. I really thought I would get a network request with a 404 http response if it was down. I don't know why the network request never got sent out, when AWS was down.